# How to get clipboard data using python irrespective of format?

Tags: python, windows, clipboard, pywin32

`win32clipboard.GetClipboardData(win32clipboard.CF_TEXT)`
I tried win32clipboard but here we need to specify the format. Is there any way to get data without specifying any particular format.
Any library will be helpful.

Comment: I see some examples where they call the method without any arguments, does that not work?

Comment: No, that's only working for text.

Answer (score 1):

Sure! An incredible cross-platform library: [pyperclip](https://pypi.org/project/pyperclip/).

```py
import pyperclip
currently_copied_content = pyperclip.paste()
```

Comment: This package only supports plain text.

Comment: @VermaAman, yes you’re right. The question wasn’t too clear back when I posted this answer. Still, I’d keep it up in case people stumble upon this looking for a package like pyperclip.